# Programmatically rendering a Views pane with arguments from context

Tags: views, panels, chaos-tool-suite

I'm trying to programmatically render a Views pane (ie. a Pane display of a view) with a taxonomy term as argument (passed in the pane context)

The following code illustrate how the pane is rendered

```
$selected_type = 'views_panes';
$selected_subtype = 'persona_display-panel_pane_1';
$context = array(
  'context_taxonomy_term_1' => ctools_context_create('entity:taxonomy_term', $fully_loaded_taxonomy_term);
);
ctools_content_render($selected_type, $selected_subtype, array(), array(), array(), $context);
```

It mostly works and the view is rendered. However, the taxonomy term in the context is not used as argument for the view.

In the pane views display's settings, the "Argument input" for the one views' argument is configured as "Term ID" "From context":
[image]

I looked at the code for the view display handler. Arguments handling is done in [`views_content_plugin_display_panel_pane::pane_process_conf()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ctools/tree/views_content/plugins/views/views_content_plugin_display_panel_pane.inc?h=7.x-1.11#n419). I checked there and the issues seems to be that `$conf['context']` is not set. So `$context_keys` ends up being an empty array. Later in the switch statement, `$key = array_shift($context_keys)` sets `$key` to `NULL`, the `isset($contexts[$key])` test fails and the `$argument` is ignored.

I have no idea if this is a bug with Views pane, or if something is missing in the pane rendering code.

Note: I'm actually using a [Pane Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/pane_field) field in a [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) bundle.

Comment: Note that this has been cross-posted as a support request in CTools' issues queue at https://www.drupal.org/node/2827763

Comment: Perhaps, if I understood this correctly, a work around, you could set the view contextual filter to `Get taxonomy term ID from url`. This way you do not have to pass any term ID programmatically.

Comment: That does not work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with

```
$selected_type = 'views_panes';
$selected_subtype = 'persona_display-panel_pane_1';
$context = array(
  'context_taxonomy_term_1' => ctools_context_create('entity:taxonomy_term', $fully_loaded_taxonomy_term);
);
$config = array(
  'context' => array('context_taxonomy_term_1');
);
ctools_content_render($selected_type, $selected_subtype, $config, array(), array(), $context);
```

So, in order to render a Views Pane display with contextual filters coming from the pane's context you to populate `$context` and inform the display handler on which entries of `$context` to use for each contextual filter with `$config['context']`.